# UIImageView animationDuration with fade effects

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I'am searching for a (very) simple way to crossfade images within animationDuration time. I tried using NSTimer and some other stuff I found here, but no solution satisfy or helps me.

I create this stuff in a method (without comments) ...

```
- (UIImageView *)playSequence{
    NSArray *structureArray = self.contenManager.ImageViewControllerSize;
    NSMutableArray *structuresToPlay = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    // walk thru current collection
    for(NSInteger i = 0; i < [self.currentCollection count]; i++)
    {
        NSInteger index = [[self.currentCollection objectAtIndex:i] integerValue];
        [structuresToPlay addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:[structureArray objectAtIndex:index]]];
    }

    _playSequence = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768)];
    _playSequence.animationImages = structuresToPlay;
    _playSequence.animationDuration = 5 * structuresToPlay.count;

    [_playSequence startAnimating];
    return _playSequence;
}
```

Here is the part where the method is called ...

```
- (void)justPlaySelection
{
    UIView *justPlaySelection = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768)];

    // some background music code ...

    // add play sequence
    [justPlaySelection addSubview:self.playSequence];

    // add close button
    // { ... }

    [self presentSemiView:justPlaySelection];
```

}

Comment: What's the exact effect you want to achieve? To crossfade images I usually use two `UIImageView` and load the new images in the `completion` block of the animation.

Comment: Did you have tried UIView animation like this -- >      [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f animations:^{
        
        // your animation
        
    } completion:^(BOOL completedt){
        
    }];

Comment: Yes I mean crossfading and yes, I tried UIView animate. To show the images, I use UIViewController+KNSemiModal - maybe heres the problem?

Comment: Can you describe how the current code's effect looks like?

Comment: Only simple slide show. Shure it works great, but it's hard for the eyes :)

Comment: I added the method which calls > playSequence <

Answer (score 0):

```
- (UIImageView *)playSequence
{
   if (_playSequence == nil)
    {
     NSArray *structureArray = self.contenManager.ImageViewControllerSize;
        NSMutableArray *structuresToPlay = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        // walk thru current collection
        for(NSInteger i = 0; i < [self.currentCollection count]; i++)
        {
            NSInteger index = [[self.currentCollection objectAtIndex:i] integerValue];
            [structuresToPlay addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:[structureArray objectAtIndex:index]]];
        }

        _playSequence = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768)];

    }

    _playSequence.animationImages = structuresToPlay;
    _playSequence.animationDuration = 5 * structuresToPlay.count;

    [_playSequence startAnimating];
    return _playSequence;

}
```

Comment: Mmmhh ... and where's the crossfade solution?

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to switch between to UIImageViews, it wouldn't be hard to add in the fade in and out.

```
- (void) performAnimationOfFrameAtIndex:(NSNumber*)indexNum
{
    int index = indexNum.intValue;

    BOOL completedSequece = index >= [self.frames count];

    if (completedSequece) return;

    UIImageView *imgIn;
    UIImageView *imgOut;

    if (index % 2 == 0) {
        imgIn = self.animationImageViewOne;
        imgOut = self.animationImageViewTwo;
    }
    else {
        imgIn = self.animationImageViewTwo;
        imgOut = self.animationImageViewOne;
    }

    imgIn.image = [self.frames objectAtIndex:index];
    [self.view sendSubviewToBack:imgOut];

    double speed = 0.1;

    [self performSelector:@selector(performAnimationOfFrameAtIndex:) withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:index + 1] afterDelay:speed];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a project that does exactly what you describe (an effect like UIImageView animation sequence, but with a cross-fade between images.)

The project is on github: https://github.com/DuncanMC/Animate-Img

You need to have 2 image views.

The trick I use is to stack them on top of each other, and simply animate the top image view from alpha 1 -> 0, then switch images in the top image view and animate it from alpha 0 -> 1.0, so the new image is revealed.

The project demos a morph transition using only 5 frames. Each frame is marked with a number so you can see the frame changes. It has a switch which lets you turn cross-fading on or off.